# Does Visual Studio (MSBuild) resolve from the solution or project directory?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, project, solution, resolve

Using relative paths to include BeforeBuild MSBuild tasks to ensure dependencies are built first.

Our folder structure is Solution Folder --> Solution --> Project Folder --> Project.

Does MSBuild resolve starting from the solution folder, or the project folder?

Thanks!

Comment: To MSBuild the VS Solution is just a container - dependencies are resolved entirely by Project References, so your folder structure doesn't really matter. You could reference a Project from a different Solution folder and MSBuild will still be able to figure out the build order. You might want to explain why you need dedicated tasks to build dependencies. (and I did not DV, just for the record)

Comment: We have dependencies spread across multiple solutions.  Huge ancient application with 56 disparate components.  We tried to use NuGet for dependency management, but ran into issues with Developers not paying attention to whether the package they pulled was part of their specific branch or not.  Current procedure is to manually build all these solutions separately - trying to do a better job of tying them together via MSBuild tasks.

Comment: That clears the picture and prepares answerers suggesting NuGet as a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of your file path. When in doubt, you can use `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` or `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` to ensure you have the right location.